# how to remove duplication from this c# code block

Tags: c#

I wrote this code but during code review process it was suggested that this is duplicate code and I need to remove code duplication from this code. Can anyone suggest how I can make this code better to avoid duplication.

```
private void ShowHideEmailContents(string email, string email2, string format, string tooltip, bool isReadOnly)
{
    if (isReadOnly)
    {
        hlEmail.NavigateUrl = string.Format(format, email);
        hlEmail2.NavigateUrl = string.Format(format, email2);
        hlEmail.Text = email;
        hlEmail2.Text = email2;
        hlEmail.ToolTip = tooltip;
        hlEmail2.ToolTip = tooltip;
        hlEmail.Visible = isReadOnly;
        hlEmail2.Visible = isReadOnly;
        txtEmail.Visible = !isReadOnly;
        txtEmail2.Visible = !isReadOnly;
    }
    else
    {
        txtEmail.Text = email;
        txtEmail2.Text = email2;
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site exists.

Comment: Why don't you ask your reviewer? That's what a review is for, *giving you a solution to a better program*. If it's only used to criticize your code, or you are too afraid to ask *how do I do this*, then you really need to work on your review process!

Comment: @nvoigt It's true that you should ask the reviewer. But I think he doesn't owe you a complete solution, he should at least give you a hint though.

Comment: @CodeMonkey It's likely his colleague. Most likely, it's even his *job* to do the review and it seems he's only doing half of it (the criticizing).

Comment: @nvoigt I do agree with you that he isn't doing his full job. I just think the reviewers duty is to see that this duplication exists, and then point out how the code is duplicated. But not necessarily how else it should be implemented.

Comment: @nvoigt. i was told that i am experienced dev so should be able to figure out myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the duplication exists because you do the same things *twice*, just on different objects.

To fix that, create a new method which does those things only *once*:

```
private static void ShowHideEmailContents(?? hl, ?? txt, string email, string format, string tooltip, bool isReadOnly)
{
    if (isReadOnly)
    {
        hl.NavigateUrl = string.Format(format, email);
        hl.Text = email;
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        txt.Text = email;
    }
}
```

and *call it twice*:

```
private void ShowHideEmailContents(string email, string email2, string format, string tooltip, bool isReadOnly)
{
    ShowHideEmailContents(hlEmail, txtEmail, email, format, tooltip, isReadOnly);
    ShowHideEmailContents(hlEmail2, txtEmail2, email2, format, tooltip, isReadOnly);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can minimise the number of parameters that you pass by encapsulating the logic to set the email object's properties in a class:

```
public sealed class EmailOptionsSetter
{
    readonly string _tooltip;
    readonly string _format;
    readonly bool   _isReadOnly;

    public EmailOptionsSetter(string tooltip, string format, bool isReadOnly)
    {
        _tooltip    = tooltip;
        _format     = format;
        _isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    }

    public void SetOptions(YourEmailType emailObj, string email)
    {
        emailObj.NavigateUrl = string.Format(_format, email);
        emailObj.Text        = email;
        emailObj.ToolTip     = _tooltip;
        emailObj.Visible     = _isReadOnly;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
    private void ShowHideEmailContents(string email, string email2, string format, string tooltip, bool isReadOnly)
    {
        if (isReadOnly)
        {
            var optionsSetter = new EmailOptionsSetter(tooltip, format, isReadOnly);
            optionsSetter.SetOptions(hlEmail, email);
            optionsSetter.SetOptions(hlEmail2, email2);

            txtEmail.Visible  = !isReadOnly;
            txtEmail2.Visible = !isReadOnly;            
        }
        else
        {
            txtEmail.Text  = email;
            txtEmail2.Text = email2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is this better?

Comment: @Mardoxx Better than what? The OP? Because duplicate code is removed. Or better than using a method? Because it means passing only two parameters (when setting) rather than five, although you still need 3 parameters for the constructor. Also you can separate out the validation of the options (in the ctor) from the actual using of the options. Of course, opinions of what is a reasonable number of parameters differ. Some folks think that 5 is too many (and some even think that 4 is too many!). YMMV.

Comment: Of course, `ShowHideEmailContents()` itself could be considered to have too many parameters - some of the parameters should probably be encapsulated into a class of their own.

Comment: @Mardoxx [This article from Robert Martin](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1375308) discusses a similar approach to reducing the number of parameters. He says *Functions should have a small number of arguments. No argument is best, followed by one, two, and three. More than three is very questionable and should be avoided with prejudice.*

Comment: I just thought it still seems rather "messy" code and if anything, less clear than OP's. It seems OP is trying for good coding style and best practicies, but going a bit overboard with avoiding even a ittle bit of duplicate code!! Thanks for your explanation :)

Comment: Oh I understand what he's trying to do now! - Good answer then